# Optimize an array function

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

Here is an example of test code. I wonder how to optimize this code, knowing that in my development code, the original array comes from an API that I retrieve, then that I transform according to my needs and calculations in a class with functions methods (there is a lot of transformation in `$rep` with ternary operators). The example here is for simplicity:

When you call the function `testArray()` several hundred times, the calculation time begins to become long, too long. I wonder if there's a way to optimize this and code more elegantly.

```
 $data = array(
        "lemon" => 'test1',
        "tomato" => 'test2',
        "cofee" => 'test3',
        "tree" => 'test4'
    );
    
    
    function testArray($data)
    {
    
        $rep = array(
            'yellow' => $data['lemon'],
            'red' => $data['tomato'],
            'brown' => $data['cofee'],
            'green' => $data['tree']
        );
        return $rep;
    }
    
    echo testArray($data)['yellow'];    // test1
    echo testArray($data)['red'];       // test2
    echo testArray($data)['brown'];     // test3
    echo testArray($data)['green'];     // test4
```

thank you, I'm stuck a bit to find a more efficient way.

Comment: Well, if I understand your question correctly, you left out the code which could be optimised.

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact use case but perhaps a 'generator' could be of use to you? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: I don't know the generators, I will find out. Do you have an idea if not how to use it with my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call the function multiple time. Just store it to a variable and use it later.

```php
$data = array(
        "lemon" => 'test1',
        "tomato" => 'test2',
        "cofee" => 'test3',
        "tree" => 'test4'
    );
    
    
    function testArray($data)
    {
    
        $rep = array(
            'yellow' => $data['lemon'],
            'red' => $data['tomato'],
            'brown' => $data['cofee'],
            'green' => $data['tree']
        );
        return $rep;
    }
    
    $transformedData = testArray($data);
    echo transformedData['yellow'];    // test1
    echo transformedData['red'];       // test2
    echo transformedData['brown'];     // test3
    echo transformedData['green'];     // test4
```

Comment: Wow, you just saw the thing that no one sees, ....... :-O

Comment: so obvious now that you say it

Comment: I hope that this answer gets 1 million upvotes

Comment: The calculation time has been divided almost by 10. Thank you very much. I suspected it was something stupid like that, I just didn't see it, like the nose in the middle of the face ^^

Comment: And even divided by 20 or 30. What took 15 seconds to display, only takes half a second after corrections. Like what, small change, big effect...

Comment: @Networkbell, the time complexity actually is reduced from `O(N^2)` to `O(N)`.